# onKeyDown() doesn't work on extended class

Tags: android

I create a custom GalleryView and it work with my devices (Samsung Galaxy S III & Nexus 4), But when I try to use it in my emulator I got the following errors!!!

```
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429):     at android.view.ViewRoot.playSoundEffect(ViewRoot.java:2581)
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429):     at android.view.View.playSoundEffect(View.java:8516)
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429):     at android.widget.Gallery.onKeyDown(Gallery.java:1109)
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429):     at com.example.coverflow.ui.galleryView$1.run(galleryView.java:55)
02-24 01:01:03.593: E/AndroidRuntime(3429):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

These errors mention to the following lines of my code:

```
public void startSlideShow(final int periodTime)
{
    final Runnable __runnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            if (!isTouched) 
                galleryView.this.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, periodTime);              
        }
    };
    new Thread(__runnable).start();

    this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
        {
            int currentEvent = event.getAction();
            if (currentEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
                    || currentEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                isTouched = true;
            else
            {
                isTouched = false;
                // Reset handler
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(__runnable);
                mHandler.postDelayed(__runnable, periodTime);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

***Line 55 is*** `galleryView.this.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);`

What should I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update UI from other thread than the activity UI thread.

Like the error says:

```
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Try wrapping your file access code with `runOnUIThread(new Runnable{ ...  }())`

Example: [Can i have an example of displaying a toast using runOnUiThread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791157/can-i-have-an-example-of-displaying-a-toast-using-runonuithread)

Comment: So why it's worked with my phone and doesn't worked in emulator!?

Comment: This exception should have been thrown on both, and you probably changed something between runs.