# facebook, android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running

Tags: android, facebook, illegalstateexception

After login I can I can make FB queries. After few minutes (played game) Facebook requests fail exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running
```

It fails when I call

```
        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(),
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {...

        Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(),
                "me/apprequests", new Request.Callback() {...

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/apprequests", null,
                    null, new Request.Callback() { .... } );
        RequestAsyncTask status = request.executeAsync();
```

Same calls are called immediately after login and they work.
I have a test app where it works. But in real app after few minutes after login it does not work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you running on UI thread? Wrap your code with`runOnUiThread`

like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791157/can-i-have-an-example-of-displaying-a-toast-using-runonuithread)

Facebook SDK [mentions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/) that async calls must be done from UI thread

Answer (score 4):

You can use Request.toHttpConnection(request) instead of request.executeAsync()