# cannot execute task : the task is already running

Tags: android, facebook, android-asynctask

I developed a game that shares video on FB, it was working well before but I dunno how now I'm getting this error. Also I was getting all permission and now it's not giving me any.
And in FB RequestAsyncTask class I made some modifications for AlertDialog that show process of uploading video.

Here is where I'm executing AsyncTask

```
Request request = new Request(session, "me/videos", postParam, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
RequestAsyncTask reqTask = new RequestAsyncTask(Result.this, request);
reqTask.execute();
```

And Logcat

```
04-19 18:40:47.048: I/System.out(20093): no of permission it has = 0
04-19 18:40:47.963: D/AndroidRuntime(20093): Shutting down VM
04-19 18:40:47.963: W/dalvikvm(20093): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418cb700)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:575)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask.executeOnSettingsExecutor(RequestAsyncTask.java:205)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.Request.executeBatchAsync(Request.java:1094)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.RequestBatch.executeAsyncImpl(RequestBatch.java:225)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.RequestBatch.executeAsync(RequestBatch.java:204)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.validateSameFbidAndFinish(AuthorizationClient.java:279)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.completeAndValidate(AuthorizationClient.java:215)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.getTokenCompleted(AuthorizationClient.java:536)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler$1.completed(AuthorizationClient.java:514)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient.callback(GetTokenClient.java:121)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient.handleMessage(GetTokenClient.java:107)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient.access$0(GetTokenClient.java:100)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.facebook.GetTokenClient$1.handleMessage(GetTokenClient.java:43)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
04-19 18:40:47.968: E/AndroidRuntime(20093):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 18:40:59.128: I/Process(20093): Sending signal. PID: 20093 SIG: 9
04-19 18:40:59.463: I/dalvikvm(20943): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
```

if anyone wanna look at any other part of code just let me know I'll give you. ASAP I need to debug this and upload to Google Play

**EDIT**

here is whole code where I'm using fb post, After replace project into new one it was working but after I change application name on FB Developer it ask permission that is normal then it start to give me same error again.

```
package com.yceo.anlatbana;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.yceo.anlatbana.R;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.RequestAsyncTask;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.Session.StatusCallback;
import com.yceo.anlatbana.util.ListViewAdapter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;


public class Result extends Activity {

    static final String APP_ID = "dont wanna show";
    Session session;
    private boolean pendingRequest;
    static final String PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.yceo.anlatbana:PendingRequest";
    static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

    private TextView result;
    private Button re_play;
    private Button save_video;
    private Button watch_video;
    private Button share_video;
    private ImageView score_top;
    private ImageView score;

    public static int isSaved = 0;
    public static int doubleClick = 0;
    public static int sentAlready = 0;

    public static int width;
    public static int height;

    int resultPoint;

    private Typeface font_score;

    String path = VideoViewTest.videoPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        this.session = createSession();
        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        re_play= (Button) findViewById(R.id.result_button_replay);
        save_video= (Button) findViewById(R.id.result_button_save_video);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_result_tw);
        watch_video= (Button) findViewById(R.id.result_button_play_video);
        share_video= (Button) findViewById(R.id.result_button_share_video);

        score_top= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iw_result_point_top);
        score= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_score);

        font_score=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/PATAGONIA.TTF");

        int trueNumber = VideoViewTest.true_answers.size();
        int falseNumber = VideoViewTest.false_answers.size();

        resultPoint = ((trueNumber*9) - (falseNumber*2));

        result.setText(String.valueOf(resultPoint));
        result.setTypeface(font_score);
        result.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (int)(width*0.05));


        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_button1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.1)), ((int)(width*0.1)));
        lp_result_button1.setMargins(((int)(width*0.035)), 0, ((int)(width*0.035)), 0);
        lp_result_button1.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.result_button_save_video);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_button2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.1)), ((int)(width*0.1)));
        lp_result_button2.setMargins(((int)(width*0.035)), 0, ((int)(width*0.035)), 0);
        lp_result_button2.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.result_result_tw);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_button3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.1)), ((int)(width*0.1)));
        lp_result_button3.setMargins(((int)(width*0.035)), 0, ((int)(width*0.035)), 0);
        lp_result_button3.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_button4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.1)), ((int)(width*0.1)));
        lp_result_button4.setMargins(((int)(width*0.035)), 0, ((int)(width*0.035)), 0);
        lp_result_button4.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.result_result_tw);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_button5 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.1)), ((int)(width*0.1)));
        lp_result_button5.setMargins(((int)(width*0.035)), 0, ((int)(width*0.035)), 0);
        lp_result_button5.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.result_button_play_video);

        re_play.setLayoutParams(lp_result_button1);
        save_video.setLayoutParams(lp_result_button2);
        result.setLayoutParams(lp_result_button3);
        watch_video.setLayoutParams(lp_result_button4);
        share_video.setLayoutParams(lp_result_button5);

        score_top.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.0654545)), ((int)(width*0.0341818))));
        score.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width*0.1)), ((int)(width*0.1))));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_llw = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width/2)-((int)(width*0.16))), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp_result_llw.setMargins(((int)(width*0.15)), 0, ((int)(width*0.01)), 0);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_result_rlw = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(((int)(width/2)-((int)(width*0.16))), LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp_result_rlw.setMargins(((int)(width*0.01)), 0, ((int)(width*0.15)), 0);

        final ListView correct_answer_lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result_correct_lw);
        final ListView wrong_answer_lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.result_wrong_lw);

        correct_answer_lw.setLayoutParams(lp_result_llw);
        wrong_answer_lw.setLayoutParams(lp_result_rlw);

        ListViewAdapter adapter_correct_lw = new ListViewAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.item_correct_answer, 
                R.id.item_correct, 
                VideoViewTest.true_answers,
                height);

        correct_answer_lw.setAdapter(adapter_correct_lw);
        adapter_correct_lw.notifyDataSetChanged();

        ListViewAdapter adapter_wrong_lw = new ListViewAdapter(
                this, 
                R.layout.item_wrong_answer, 
                R.id.item_wrong, 
                VideoViewTest.false_answers,
                height);

        wrong_answer_lw.setAdapter(adapter_wrong_lw);
        adapter_wrong_lw.notifyDataSetChanged();

        re_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onBackPressed();
                VideoViewTest.true_answers.clear();
                VideoViewTest.false_answers.clear();
            }
        });

        save_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Video Kaydedildi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isSaved = 1;
            }
        });

        watch_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AndroidVideoPlayer.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        share_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                clickHandler(v);
                if (doubleClick==0 && sentAlready==0) {

                    share_it();
                    doubleClick=1;
                    sentAlready=1;
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Already shared on Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (VideoViewTest.videoPath != null) {
            if (isSaved == 0) {
                File file = new File(VideoViewTest.videoPath);
                if(file.exists())
                    file.delete();
                finish();
            }
        }
        finish();
        doubleClick = 0;
        sentAlready = 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        doubleClick=0;
//      Log.i("pause", "oldu");
        super.onPause();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (this.session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data)
                && pendingRequest && this.session.getState().isOpened()) {
            share_it();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        pendingRequest = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
        bundle.putBoolean(PENDING_REQUEST_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingRequest);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private Session createSession() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null || session.getState().isClosed()) {
            session = new Session.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setApplicationId(APP_ID).build();
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
        }
        return session;
    }

    public void clickHandler(View v) {
        if (!session.isOpened()) {
            StatusCallback callback = new StatusCallback() {

                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (exception != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Result.this.session = createSession();
                    }
                }
            };

            pendingRequest = true;
            this.session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(callback));
        }
    }

    public void share_it() {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            if (session != null) {
                List<String> permission = session.getPermissions();
                System.out.println("no of permission it has = " + permission.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < permission.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Permission " + i + " => " + permission.get(i));
                }
                if (permission.size() == 0) {
                    pendingRequest = true;
                    Session.NewPermissionsRequest publishPermission = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
                    session.requestNewPublishPermissions(publishPermission);
                } 
                else {

                    final Bundle postParam = new Bundle();
                    String dataMsg = "AnlatBana Game Video";

                    byte[] data = null;
//                  InputStream is = null;

                    File file=new File(path);


/*                  try {
                        is = new FileInputStream(path);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
*/                  try {
//                      data = readBytes(is);
                        data = getBytesFromFile(file);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

/*                  Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    data = baos.toByteArray();

                    postParam.putByteArray("picture", data);
*/              

                    postParam.putString("message", dataMsg);
                    postParam.putString("description", scoreDescription());
//                  postParam.putString("title", "title");
                    postParam.putString("contentType", "video/quicktime");
                    postParam.putByteArray("video.mov", data);

                    final Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String postId = null;

                            try {
                                JSONObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                                postId = graphObject.getString("id");

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.out.println("Error Occured fetching grapho objecyt " + ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/videos", postParam, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
                    RequestAsyncTask reqTask = new RequestAsyncTask(Result.this, request);
                    reqTask.execute();


/*              Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParam, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
                RequestAsyncTask reqTask = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
                reqTask.execute();
*/
                }
            }
        }
    }

/*  public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // This dynamically extends to take the bytes you read.
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        // This is storage overwritten on each iteration with bytes.
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // We need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer.
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        // And then we can return your byte array.
        return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
*/  
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        System.out.println("\nDEBUG: FileInputStream is " + file);

        // Get the size of the file
        long length = file.length();
        System.out.println("DEBUG: Length of " + file + " is " + length + "\n");

        /*
         * You cannot create an array using a long type. It needs to be an int
         * type. Before converting to an int type, check to ensure that file is
         * not loarger than Integer.MAX_VALUE;
         */
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("File is too large to process");
            return null;
        }

        // Create the byte array to hold the data
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        // Read in the bytes
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((offset < bytes.length) && ((numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0)) {
            offset += numRead;
/*          progressBar.setProgress((int) ((offset / (float) length) * 100));
            Log.i("asd", String.valueOf(progressBar.getProgress()));
*/      }

        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file);
        }

        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }

    public String scoreDescription() {
        String message = null;

        if (resultPoint < 0) {
            message = String.valueOf(resultPoint) + " Puan" + " - Yok artık!!!";
        }
        if (0 <= resultPoint && resultPoint < 10) {
            message = String.valueOf(resultPoint) + " Puan" + " - Daha çok çalışman lazım";
        }
        if (10 <= resultPoint && resultPoint < 20) {
            message = String.valueOf(resultPoint) + " Puan" + " - Fena değil";
        }
        if (20 <= resultPoint && resultPoint < 25) {
            message = String.valueOf(resultPoint) + " Puan" + " - Güzel skor";
        }
        if (25 <= resultPoint) {
            message = String.valueOf(resultPoint) + " Puan" + " - Çok hızlısın";
        }

        return message;

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556015/facebook-android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-execute-task-the-task

Comment: Sir, please, have you solved your problem? sir?, so i paste an answer?

Comment: I already solved problem after that appear and even dont remember how =), cuz it was long time ago and I did so many app after that. Btw thanks for your answer I dunno how but I wasn't signed in so I couldnt realize, apologise ;)

Answer (score 12):

An `AsyncTask` can only be executed once. Are you calling execute somewhere else in your code?

Comment: make sure you're calling the request task from the UI thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15558437/611888

Comment: I tried UI thread already for Request task and also for RequestAsyncTask both separate and together also. Still getting same error.

Comment: I think the problems related with getting permission part, cuz I'm sure I was getting all request from facebook but now size of it always 0 and I put in comment both Request and RequestAsyncTask still same error

Answer (score 12):

An instance of class AsyncTask can only be executed once. So you have to make new instance everytime you call execute().

`new ClassName().execute();`

Answer (score 2):

you can use AsyncTask more than once by  new CLASS_NAME().execute()
CLASS_NAME extends AsyncTask, without create instance from CLASS_NAME

Answer (score -1):

Simply execute your Async task in **Async Task Thread Pool**

```
new RequestAsyncTask(Result.this, 
      new Request(session, "me/videos", postParam, HttpMethod.POST, callback))
                    .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```