# How to display a Toast in Android AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

I am trying to display Toast in my initial_background class extended with `AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>`. I am receiving this error in logcat.

```
public class InitialBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        show a = new show();
        a.loop();
        return null;
    }

public class show {

    void loop()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.me, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception:

```
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at   com.example.toast.show.loop(show.java:11)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at com.example.toast.InitialBackgroundTask.doInBackground(InitialBackgroundTask.java:13)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at com.example.toast.InitialBackgroundTask.doInBackground(InitialBackgroundTask.java:1)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-30 12:08:12.641: E/AndroidRuntime(30840):    ... 5 more
```

The above code is showing the whole story. Actually, I want to show toast in doInBackground method

Comment: in doinBanckground() you can't do any UI related stuff, try displaying your toast inside PostExecute() method.

Comment: Actually, I am downloading some data from URls, and and i have four Urls i want to show toast one one url get downloaded and so on. so if i will do this in post it will cannot display one by one it will display only the end result.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot update UI on background thread. `doInBackground()` is invoked on the background thread. You should update UI on the UI thread.

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

          @Override
          public void run(){
            //update ui here
            // display toast here 
          }
       });
```

`onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute(Result)`, are invoked on the UI thread. So you can display toast here.

`onProgressUpdate(Progress...)`, invoked on the UI thread after a call to `publishProgress(Progress...)` can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.

The result of `doInBackground()` computation is a parameter to `onPostExecute(Result)` so return the result in `doinBackground()` and show your toast in `onPostExecute(Result)`

You can also use a handler as suggested by @Stine Pike

For clarity, check the link below under the topic: **The 4 steps**.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 22):

Create a handler object and execute all your Toast messages using that.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Handler handler =  new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
    handler.post( new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Created a server socket",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: what about context ?

Comment: Just trying to help you can use `Looper.getMainLooper()` if you're confused about `context.getMainLooper()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is another way which is not mentioned here as follows:

**Step 1:** Define **Handler** as global

```
Handler handler;
```

**Step 2:** Initialise handler in **doInBackground()** method as follows:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 1) {
           //your code
        }
    }
  };
}
```

**Step 3:**
   And now you can call that handler by anywhere in code by calling

```
if(handler != null){
  handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
}
```

> **What more you can do is you can send data through handler as follows:**

```
Message message = new Message();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("KEY", value);
message.setData(bundle);
handler.sendMessage(message);
```

And handle data in you handler as below

```
handler = new Handler(){ 
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Bundle bundle = message.getData();
        Integer value = bundle.getInt("KEY");

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

show your Toast in onPostExecute or onPreExecute. doInBackGround runs on a separate thread but the other two methods run on the UI thread.

But if it is must to show toast in doInBackGround then you can use [Handler.post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [runonUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to perform toast showing.

Answer (score 2):

You can't display Toast in non-UI thread (i.e Do in Background).You may try the flag concept.

```
public class HttpRequest extends AsyncTask<String[], Void, String> {
    boolean flag=false;
....
...
....
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[]... params) {
   //set flag as true when you need to trigger the Toast
 try{
   //Some Network Calls
     } catch (HttpHostConnectException e) {
    flag=true;   
  //Triggered Flas when i got Exceptions          
       }
}
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(flag){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "HttpHostConnectException Occured ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


}
```

Happy Coding..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display toast in non-ui thread that's why this error apear.

If you want to display toast in doInBackground method then you have to write your Toast logic inside UI thread

have a look in below answer link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797945/582571

**But it is not advisable to have a UI manipulation under non-ui thread**

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by passing an interface to the AsyncTask class and make a callback in **onPostExecute** method.

```
public interface IResult {
    void onSuccess(String result);
    void onError(String error);                                                  
}

public static class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {

    IResult iResult;

    AsyncTaskClass(IResult iResult){
        this.iResult = iResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result;
        try {
            //doing BackGround Operation Here
            result = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error: " + e.getMessage());
            result = false;
        }

       return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        super.onPostExecute(success);
        Log.w(TAG, "On Post Execute: " + success);
        if(success)
            iResult.onSuccess("AsyncTask done successfully.");
        else
            iResult.onSuccess("Sorry! something went wrong.");

    }
}                                                                      
  IResult iResult = new IResult() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(String result) {
          Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(String error) {
          Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  };
  String param1 = "some value 1";
  String param2 = "some value 2";

  new AsyncTaskClass(iResult).execute(param1, param2);`
```

Answer (score 0):

use sdk 29

```java
public class LoginControl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final Context context;

    public LoginControl (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
     //do something
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TokenBean tokenBean) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "hello Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

in MainActivity.class

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url="something";
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        new LoginControl(context).execute(url);
    }
```