# Cannot get file content over http

Tags: android

I use the software `YouWave Android` to test ( emulate ) my project , because my Windows 7 computer does not bear the ADT device emulator. I want to get a text file content inside my wampserver directory. The file is in my local computer at the moment. So when I click a button this code is launched :

```
public void synchroniser(View view) {
        if (webVersMobile != null) {
            if (webVersMobile.isChecked()) {
                new RequestTask().execute("http://localhost/impots/data/syncro/webVersAndroid/ruePpale.txt");
            }   
        }
    }

    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... s_url) {

            String lines = "";
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(networkInfo != null) {
                if (networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                    HttpURLConnection con = null;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    String tmp = "";
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(s_url[0]);
                        if (url != null) {
                            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            if (con != null && con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "avant get inputstream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "apres get inputstream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                                while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    lines += tmp;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dans ioexception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } finally {
                        if (reader != null) {
                          try {
                            reader.close();
                          } catch (IOException e) {
                          }
                        }
                        con.disconnect();
                    }
                }   
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No network", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return lines;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != "") {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data = "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


    }
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ambre.impots"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    ...
```

What is wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you are running the app on an emulator so localhost doesn't mean anything. Can you try to open a web browser on the emulator to check if you can access this URL ?

Comment: I changed `localhost` to the IP address and it works :) Also `Toast` is not supported by AsyncTask !

Comment: This is normal, a toast has to be run on the UI thread. Have a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830255/how-to-display-toast-in-asynctask-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top