# get main activity context for imageView

Tags: java, android, multithreading, uiimageview

I'm using thread (runOnUiThread) for adding imageView to mainActivity.
i don't know what should i import to constructor! It want context and i tried `MainActivity.this` and `getApplicationContext()` and `getBaseContext()` but it doesn't work!

```
public void addImageView(final int belowId,final int id){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RelativeLayout rSub= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rSub);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, belowId);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(?????);
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            iv.setId(id);
            rSub.addView(iv, lp);   
        }
    });
}
```

and call it :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        addImageView(belowId, tempId);
     }
}).start();
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: can you post some more of your great activity class?

Comment: What is your activity name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your `addImageView` method is not in Activity class.. Maybe in custom view.. (but that is my assumption)

So, if it is another class (not Activity class) where you implement your `addImageView` method, then:

Activity class:

```
MyCustomComponent component = new MyCustomComponent(this);
```

MyCustomComponent class:

```
private Context context;

public MyCustomComponent(Context context){
  this.context = context;
}

public void addImageView(final int belowId,final int id){
    ((Activity)this.context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       ....
    }
}
```

In case if you are running your method from the Activity, then use: (you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11797945/1276374))

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...});
```